# While loop ignores or statement

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am trying to run the while loop below for my Programming I class extra credit. It's supposed to simulate a game of craps however I can't figure out why the bottom while loop runs no matter what.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExtraCredit {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in );
        Random random = new Random( );
        int die1, die2, roll;
        int dice = 0;
        int point = 0;
        int finish = 0;
        int play = 1;

        while (play == 1)
        {

            System.out.println ("Enter 0 to roll the dice");
            roll = scan.nextInt( );

            if (roll == 0)
            {
                die1 = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
                die2 = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
                dice = die1+die2;
            }

            if (dice == 7 || dice == 11)
            {
                System.out.println ("\nYou rolled a " + dice + " on your first roll!");
                System.out.println ("You win!");
                finish = 1;
            }

            else if (dice == 2 || dice == 3 || dice == 12)
            {
                System.out.println ("You rolled a " + dice + " on your first roll!");
                System.out.println ("You lose!");
                finish = 1;
            }

            else
            {
                point = dice;
                System.out.println ("\nYour point is " + point);
                System.out.println ("You need to roll a " + point + " to win");
                System.out.println ("Enter 0 to Roll again");
                roll = scan.nextInt( );
                if (roll == 0)
                {
                    die1 = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
                    die2 = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
                    dice = die1+die2;
                }
            }

            while (dice != point || dice != 7 || finish != 1)
            {
                System.out.println ("\nYou rolled a " + dice);
                System.out.println ("Roll again");
                roll = scan.nextInt( );
                if (roll == 0)
                {
                    die1 = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
                    die2 = random.nextInt( 6 ) + 1;
                    dice = die1+die2;
                 }
            }

            if (dice == point)
            {
                System.out.println ("\nYou rolled your point (" + point +")");
                System.out.println ("You won!");
            }

            if (dice == 7)
            {
                System.out.println ("\nYou rolled a 7 before you could match your point");
                System.out.println ("You Lose!");
            }

            System.out.println ("\nEnter 1 to play again");
            play = scan.nextInt( );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(dice != point || dice != 7 || finish != 1)
```

This will never be false.
Try this

```
(dice != point && dice != 7 && finish != 1)
```

Comment: It's not true that the first will NEVER be false.  What if `point` is `7` (so the first two are the same statement)?  (But the solution is correct)

Comment: Why will it never be false. Shouldn't it check to see if any of the or statements are true? I want it to stop when either finish != 1 or dice != point or dice != 7

Comment: Sorry I was a bit to fast with this statement, as @nhgrif pointed out it will be false only if point==7 and dice==7 and finish==1

Comment: But looking at the code before this condition, my statement is correct, as in case when dice==7 you set finish to 1 but point is 0, we have `true`

Answer (score 1):

You want to change the ||'s to &&'s

```
while (dice != point && dice != 7 && finish != 1)
```

Comment: But it should skip the while loop if any of those are true.

Comment: Ok look at it this way. Let's say that dice = 7. Obviousy point is not 7 in  a dice game, but the game will still run because it meets the condtion of `dice != point`. So that `d != 7` is ineffective.